# I've been paid half my monthly salary what are my rights? (UK)

Tags: salary, united-kingdom

At our workplace everyone received only half of their monthly salary.

Management told us this is because they haven't received as much funding as expected and have yet to give us a date as to when we should receive this money.

What are my rights on the matter? Can I be forced to come in even though they are not paying me correctly​?

Comment: https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/work/rights-at-work/pay/problems-getting-paid/

Comment: "*What are my rights on the matter?*" Is likely too broad to answer here unless you want to use this question as a canonical reference question which basically rehashes the info [Citizens Advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/work/rights-at-work/pay/problems-getting-paid/) and [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/employment-tribunals/when-you-can-claim) provide.

Comment: Trying to get the rest of your pay is smart, but it goes without saying that you should be looking for another job immediately.

Comment: This is a pretty outrageous way for a company to behave, so you certainly need to be looking for another job at once.  The company has failed and is already circling the drain; your choices are to look for another job now while you are still employed and in a stronger position, or wait until the company inevitably folds (which sounds like it's imminent) and makes you redundant.

Comment: I know I've seen very similar questions before, but I'm not having any luck finding potential duplicates.

Comment: Same as http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/late-payment-by-employer/20973#20973

Comment: Your rights almost certainly do not matter - there is no money. By the time a company fails to make payroll, it will have borrowed on any capital assets it has. No high risk lender sees a good enough prospect of viability and funding to lend half a months payroll. You might as well carry on working just in case they get funding, and to look employed, but your top priority should be your job search.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

As Ben said in the comments, Citizens Advice is your first stop.

It sounds like the company is having a cash flow issue at the moment. If you go in, crack on, and put some faith in your boss to solve the problem, chances are that your loyalty will be noted and appreciated.

If there are other things giving you cause for concern at work, then maybe evaluate your position in the company. Keep working while you search, it will reflect well on you with future employers.

Either way, it is in your best interest to go in to work.

EDIT:
The reasons I suggested giving the company the benefit of the doubt in the short term are:

1. They paid some, suggesting there is still some cash around
2. They explained the situation openly
3. OP should still be going into work until this is resolved (either by leaving or the company finding its feet) and a relaxed attitude is best

Comment: I would not "put some faith in your boss".  The company is literally bankrupt, they just don't want to admit it.  I would look for another job now.

Comment: I dont agree with "put some faith in your boss". He has already showed he cannot even pay the people he employed, so why on earth would you trust him? If he appreciated your loyalty then you would have your pay. I would be looking for another job.

Comment: @JimClay If "literally bankrupt", they would have to call in administrators. This would be announced to all employees, as is required by UK law. Cash flow problems happen. While there is nothing stopping OP from seeking other employment, that very action could be the final straw for the company. As I said, OP should consider any other factors before walking out, but should **definitely** turn up to work (the basis of the question)

Comment: They company may not be literally bankrupt, but they are already a failed company that is circling the drain.  Your answer is terrible advice.The company has already reneged on its obligations to pay its staff, and only a fool would even consider staying there one second longer than contractually obliged to.  OP should go to work while he is looking for another job.

Comment: If the company is trading while insolvent then it is already breaking the law, let alone screwing the OP over.  But if you are prepared to `put some faith in your boss` (which I disagree with) then what timeframe do you place on this 'trust'?  1 week? 1 month? 1 year?

Comment: I know about one boss who didn't have the money to pay his workers on time, but had the money to buy a brand new Ferrari for his wife. "Your loyalty will be noted and appreciated". Noticed, appreciated, but highly unlikely to be rewarded.